# find and replace using linux

Tags: regex, linux, sed, awk

I am trying to transfer a text using regex to match : O followed by space and a random number and then a new line

Example :

```
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffO 11

ffffffffffffffffO 145

fffffffffffffffffffffffffO 257

fffffffffffO 47

fffffffffffffffffffO 1

ffffffffffffO 85

fffffffffffffffffffffffO 144

fffffffffffffffO 356
```

and make it like this :

```
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff

ffffffffffffffff

fffffffffffffffffffffffff

fffffffffff

fffffffffffffffffff

ffffffffffff

fffffffffffffffffffffff

fffffffffffffff
```

using sed or awk ...

any idea ?

Comment: Are you doing this once or many times? You could easily do this in vim or many other text editors.

Comment: how to do it using vim or gedit ? the number is random !

Comment: I believe that `:%s/O [0-9]\+//g` would work in vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
awk -F "O" '{ $2=""; print $0}' file.txt
```

or the shorter version of Jotne:

```
awk -F\O '{$2=""}1'
```

As glenn jackman suggests it, you can print only the needed part:

```
awk -F "O" '{ print $1}' file.txt
```

However, these commands don't care if there is another `O` in the line and if there is a number or not at the end of the line.

Comment: You might as well just `print $1` instead of emptying $2

Comment: but must apply only this regix if it match at the end of the line ! @JamCon

Comment: "fffffffffffffff" is a random text , not only f characters @JamCon

Comment: Or shorter `awk -F\O '{$2=""}1'`

Comment: @Jotne: what the 1 means (I obtain the same result with an other integers, relative or not except zero)?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Any number other than `0` means true.  If some is true and no action is given, do default action. So `1` = `1 {print}` = `1 {print $0}`.  This is just to say, print the line.

Answer (score 3):

sed

```
sed -i 's/O [0-9]\+$//' file
```

Comment: IMO, the cleanest way.

Answer (score 1):

And here's now to do it in sed:

`sed -i 's/O\ [0-9]\+//g' file.txt`

Edit:
If it has to end with "O [0-9]*", then put a $ at the end of the regex to anchor it to the end of the line.

`sed -i 's/O\ [0-9]\+$//g' file.txt`

Comment: a space is not a special character for sed's regular expressions, so it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: True enough ... it's a force of habit when dealing with regex in a multitude of languages.  It almost never hurts, and it ends up being more portable without having to think about it.

Comment: This might match an `O` followed by a space with no number.

Answer (score 0):

Does Perl oneliner will do for you?

```
perl -i.bak -p -e "s/(.*)O.*/$1/g" input.txt
```